# Admin and normal user login system PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have some code which attempts to check whether a user is an admin or normal user, and then compares it against an SQL table to determine which page opens up (admin page vs normal user page).

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $admin = $_POST['admin'];

    if( $user == "" || $pass == "")
    {
        echo '<div id ="errormsg">Please fill in all fields</div>';
    }

    else 
    {
        $query = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'
        and password = '$pass' and admin = '$admin' ") or die ("Can't query the database");
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if($count == 1) 
        {
            if ($admin == 1)
            {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
                header("location: admin.php");
            }
            else if ($admin == 0)
            {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
                header("location: users.php");
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<div id="errormsg">No matches, try again</div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are no errors, however the admin value doesn't seem to make a difference and by default opens `'users.php'` everytime. The $admin is a checkbox with value '1' when checked, the logic being to check this value against the database. Can anyone help solve this issue?

This is the html form:

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <label class="login">Username:</label><input type="text" name="user" /><br />
    <label class="login">Password:</label><input type="password" name="pass" /><br />
    <label class="login">Admin?:</label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="admin" /><br/>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
  </fieldset>
</form
```

Comment: Show us the html for `admin` select

Comment: the admin value does work as it shows up appropriately in the sql table via phpmyadmin

Comment: @OP: Use prepared statements correctly to avoid SQLi

Comment: @ajm You admin value in your code doesn't come from database. You are capturing a `$_POST` variable in `$admin` look ====> `$admin = $_POST['admin'];`

Comment: try encapsulation the value in quotes like `($admin == "1")`

Comment: or you can also try instead of `$admin = $_POST['admin'];` USE `$admin = (!empty($_POST['admin'])?1:0);`

Answer (score 1):

The error is how you check if user is admin:

```
if ($admin == 1)
```

Replace this with:

```
if (isset($admin))
```

Also, you need to `exit` or `die` after using `header()`:

```
if (isset($admin))
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
    header("location: admin.php");
    exit;
} else {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
    header("location: users.php");
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to have a read up on mysql escaping / best practices. Your script here is vulnerable to SQL injection. 
There are plenty of good resources online, or search [SQL injection PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%20SQL%20injection%20PHP) on here, to help explain this to you if unsure.

How is the `$_POST['admin']` value set, can you post an example of your form here?
I'm guessing that the value being sent in isn't matching your conditions above so this is likely to be the cause.

It could be as simple as changing your if statement to be `===` rather than `==`, but to be sure I'd need to see your form's source core.

Comment: I understand about the injections and protection it simply isn't necessary for this task which is a small private project. I have posted the html form in my edited question

Comment: You need to check for the admin value as a string - just put quotes around the 1 - if($admin == '1') { }

Comment: That has worked for logging on correctly, however for non-admin users i now get an error regarding the $admin variable! out of the frying pan..

Comment: Try using just an else for your 2nd case - they're either admin or not. I think your final 'else' actually wants to be after the if count == clause as that's where there's no match at all in the database? Good luck :)

Comment: If count == 1 that means there is a match though? I want to simplify it like you say but it may need further explaining

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with some correction in database query-

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$user."'' and password = '".$pass."''") or die ("Can't query the database");
```

Hope it will help.